# VSCode extension TreeView Issue not selecting tree item

Tags: treeview, vscode-extensions

I'm looking to programmatically select a tree item in a TreeView. This is my code:

```
var it = seqItems[passItem.passNum-1];
this.sequenceView.reveal(it, {select: true, focus: true, expand: false});
```

Is this function implemented?

Comment: Yes, `reveal` is implemented.  You must pass in a `TreeItem` as the first argument.  Is `it` a `TreeItem`? Or something that extends a `TreeItem`?  You "might" be able to get it to work with `var it = new TreeItem(seqItems[passItem.passNum-1]);`

Comment: seqItems is the original array of a SequenceItem class that extends TreeItem. For some reason though, nothing is happening still. Here is the code. I can't find what is wrong with it: https://github.com/VisualText/vscode-nlp/pull/468

Comment: I don't know that much about classes in javascript, but I implemented my treeView ala https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/tree-view.  In your code I didn't see a `super` or constructor or class extending TreeItem (I saw an interface though).  How do your create `new SequenceItem()`'s?  I probably just missed it in your code.

Comment: The VSCode compiler will not let it compile unless "reveal" is handed the correct type which in this case is SequenceItem which extends vscode.TreeItem (see https://github.com/dehilsterlexis/vscode-nlp/blob/aebafeced30d3912be6fc47225f2678688d0337d/src/sequenceView.ts#L13)